# Некоторые клиенты не могут загрузить SQLite.Interop.dll

Tags: c#, sqlite

Есть приложение, которое использует SQLite. Ссылка на System.Data.SQLite и SQLite.Interop.dll (для платформ х64 и х86) добавлены статично, версия 1.0.112.0. (у всех 3 файлов) (В тестовый проект SQLite была добавлена через NuGet, а оттуда скопирована в текущий проект). Файлы System.Data.SQLite и SQLite.Interop.dll (в папках х86 и х64) присутствуют на клиентской машине. Версия .Net 4.7.2.

Большинство клиентов работают нормально, но несколько выбрасывают исключение с текстом "Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll'".
На своей машине собирал версии под х86 и х64, в каждом случае грузилась SQLite.Interop.dll из соответствующей папки (Если по соответсвующему пути не лежала SQLite.Interop.dll, то было исключение).

В сторону чего смотреть, чтобы избежать такого исключения на всех машинах клиентов?

Есть догадка, что у клиента отсутствует Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable. Я могу каким-то образом поместить локальную копию этого компонента в свое приложение? - Версия не верна, на машине уже установлен Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable.

Следующее предположение - система может найти SQLite.Interop.dll, но во время загрузки или инициализации случается ошибка, которая оберткой (System.Data.SQLite) трактуется как DllNotFoundException.

Comment: А версии библиотек совпадают?

Comment: @SmorcIRL, совпадают.

Comment: SQLite.Interop.dll это обертка для неуправляемых библиотек, когда она не может загрузить неуправляемую библиотеку она свалится, а вы получите "Unable to load DLL". Наверное, вам стоит смотреть на что ссылается эта dll каким-нибудь инструментом. Если была бы проблема в разрядности, то корневое исключение было бы [BadImageFormatException](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.badimageformatexception?view=net-5.0)

Comment: И проверьте, что у вас библиотеки в [соответствующих директориях](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38599849/7612728) x86 и x64 находятся

Comment: @АртёмОконечников, она ссылается на kernel32, advapi32 и msvcr120 (Смотрел через Dependency Walker). Эти либы  есть на машине (C:\Windows\System32) на которой наблюдается проблема. Библиотеки на своих местах - инча бы была ошибка на всех машинах.

Comment: А как вы добавили ссылку на SQLite.Interop.dll "статично"? Если по-идеи её должна загружать System.Data.SQLite в зависимости от платформы?

Comment: @АртёмОконечников, статично добавлена ссылка на System.Data.SQLiteб т.е. не через NuGet. Возможно, я нашел в чем проблема, проверяю.

Comment: Ну и последнее. Я, конечно, не специалист по SQLLite но установлены ли клиентские библиотеки самой базы (если они нужны) на тех машинах, где не работает?

Comment: Т.е. интероп скорее всего работает с клинтской библиотекой, что-то с названием SQLliteVER.dll

Comment: @АртёмОконечников, SQLite - встраиваемое решение, ей достаточно System.Data.SQLite и SQLite.Interop.dll. Получилось запустить приложение на проблемной машине, если собрать версию для х64. Оказалось, что на машине нет msvcr для версии х86. Простое добваление этого файла не решило проблему.

Comment: Ну встраивает же она не чудо и библиотека *.interop намекает об этом :-) Т.е проблема решена, я так понимаю?

Comment: @АртёмОконечников, решена. Спасибо за посильную помощь!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После длительного поиска была найдена причина появления DllNotFoundException. Это связано с тем, что SQLite.Interop.dll имеет зависимость от msvcr120. (Для выяснения этого использовался Dependency Walker). Но тут есть один нюанс, если приложение для платформы х64, то этот файл ожидается найти в папке C:\Windows\System32. Но если платформа х86, то файл должен быть по пути C:\Windows\SysWOW64. Я увидел что msvcr120 есть в папке System32 и решил что раз либа есть, то проблема в другом.

Самое простое решение - собирать приложение под платформу х86, а рядом с exe-файлом размещать соответствующий msvcr120.

Нашел более оптимальное решение проблемы. Соответствующая версия msvcr120 размещается рядом с SQLite.Interop.dll в папке х86 или х64. Перед использованием sqlite (например в кострукторе Application или в его перегруженном методе OnStartup()) нужно добавить нашу папку в переменную окружения PATH.

```
var pathVar = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");
       
string customDllFolder;
if (Environment.Is64BitProcess)
{
    customDllFolder = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "x64");
}
else
{
    customDllFolder = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "x86");
}

pathVar = string.Concat(pathVar, ";", customDllFolder);
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", pathVar, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

Это решение лучше, так как мы будем использовать локальную копию msvcr120 только в том случае, если ее нет на машине пользователя. А также мы можем собирать приложение для обеих платформ (х86 и х64).
Этот подход может быть использован и для других неуправляемых библиотек.

Comment: Прошу прощения, а почему тогда просто не собрать для x64? Зачем эти сложности, в сущности, с "эмулятором" (WOW)?

Comment: @АртёмОконечников, внутренние особенности компании. Как то так это можно назвать.

Comment: Вообще .NETу все равно собираете вы для 32 или 64, код на выходе будет один и тот же. По идее, вам просто нужно собрать AnyCPU и выключить галку Prefer 32-Bit в настройках и все должно заработать как требуется.

Comment: @АртёмОконечников, возможно позже я применю другой способ, когда найду как указать, где искать msvcr120 для соответствующей платформы, по дополнительных путях без требования к установки Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable. Нужно, чтобы приложение было доступно на х86. Пока использую такое решение.